# Will my app get rejected on warnings?

Tags: warnings, appstore-approval

Will my app be rejected on warnings in the console like:
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Or does this not matter?

Comment: Well, it does matter but it *shouldn't* get your app rejected...

Comment: Not enough details to help you. Please provide what is causing your issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will only get rejected if it doesn't comply to Apple's standards ([which you can look up](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)), i.e. it crashes, has some weird behaviour, inappropriate content, plagiarism and so on. However warnings usually show you that there is something unusual in your code (or StoryBoard/XIB file). Even if it doesn't directly jeopardize your chances of getting your app into the app store I suggest you try to reorganize your constraints. Apple might change the way Xcode resolves these conflicts in the future and could possibly break your User Interface.